# PHP Form Submit (save data into a text file) not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I do have a form on my web page and I would like to save user's input (email in my case) each time the Submit button is clicked.

HTML:

```
<form id="email-form" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="ex: john@gmail.com" name="email" required>
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
         <input type="submit" class="cta animated-cta" name="submit" value="Continue">
     </div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $file = fopen('list.txt', 'a');
        fwrite($file, $email);
        fclose($file);
    }
?>
```

The problem is that nothing happens, while the code seems to be correct.
Things I've tried: Created myself the list.txt file (thought it doesn't get created automatically) | Put the script on my host to see if there's any difference (I coded it locally) | Added a PHP redirect to see if the code is executed once I click the button but isn't the case.

P.S: I do have a 'event.preventDefault();' in my javascript file which is executed once the Submit button is clicked (because I don't want the page to refresh once I click). Hovewer I've removed it but nothing changed.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that your php page is being called?

Comment: also try changing `$file = fopen('list.txt', 'a');` to `$file = fopen('list.txt', 'c');`

Comment: can you show the javascript. have you used the browser's Developer Tools to watch the console and the Network tool to see if the request it sent, and what response the server gives? Have you tried adding any logging in PHP? Have you got PHP error reporting / logging switched on, and have you checked for errors? So many debugging steps you could have taken already...

Comment: My entire code (PHP + HTML) is in index.php so there's no other page. However I just added action="" or action="index.php" to the form but there's no difference.

Comment: Please show the javascript. The HTML + PHP code you've supplied is valid.

Comment: Solved. Created an ajax call.